# How to change Border Color of TextBox on Focus in UWP

Tags: uwp

I am developing an Universal Windows Platform App using `XAML` & `C#`. I want to change Border Color of `TextBox` on Focus in UWP.

Thanks in advance for Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the *Style* of your *TextBox*, the default one you can generate via designer or take [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx). There in visual states you will find *Focused* - change whatever you want in it:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
   <Storyboard>
      ... some code
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      ... some code
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well it is actually very simple to achieve, just follow these steps:

---

Step 1. add a textbox to your page.

---

step 2. right click on your textbox and pick : "EditTemplate" \ "Edit a Copy..."

this will take you to the template designer stage.

---

step 3. check this image: https://postimg.org/image/ocdn34is1/

Comment: Your answer is perfect but i am beginner on UWP and really not finding that how to implement that all instructions given in that image. May you please provide me in more Detail. Thanks for Reply.

Comment: I Done it According to you way way.. Thanks a lot for helping me. Its Working perfect.

Comment: @shubhguru28 consider accepting the answer and upvote if this answered your question so that the answer remains on top for others who will have the same issue

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Dark Templar could you please help me to make my reputation above 15 so i will be able to vote your answer to up.